# Qt/OpenGL : Program crashes with glTexImage2D

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm having problems loading a texture.

Here is a working way :

**Works**

```
QImage t = QImage("/home/renaud/Desktop/img.jpg",0);           //LOAD IMAGE
t.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888, Qt::AutoColor);     //CONVERT TO RGBA
t = t.mirrored();                                              //MIRROR

t.save("image2.jpg", 0, -1);                                   //IMAGE SEEMS FINE

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I saved the image just to check and everything is fine.

Now, I try to load an image from a buffer like and then when I load it with `glTexImage2D` it crashes. Here is the code :

**Crashes**

```
QImage img = QImage(<Buffer containing the data>, 1920, 1080, QImage::Format_RGB888);
img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888, Qt::AutoColor);     
QImage t = img.mirrored();  

t.save("image2.jpg", 0, -1); //IMAGE SEEMS FINE

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

So in the second case, I save the image before so I can check it and the image is perfect.

Do you have any idea why It would crash on `glTexImage2D` since the image looks fine when i save it ?

**EDIT :**

Problem solved if I change `GL_RGBA` to `GL_RGB`, even while keeping the QImage conversion sur RGBA. Why ?

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3` Please stop using integers as image formats. If you need a 3 channel format, [ask for one by name](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QImage::convertToFormat` returns the new image converted, but do not modify the image itself.

Use:

```
img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888, Qt::AutoColor);
```